# make iterm show ansi by default

Tags: symfony, laravel-4, iterm2

My home and work computers are both running Mountain Lion w/ latest update.

However, on my work computer, I couldn't get ansi output by default when using `laravel` or `symfony-console` component. I need to use `--ansi` switch to get the colors. I'm using Solarized Dark color scheme.

In home computer, I don't need to set `--ansi` switch.

So, how can I set to detect terminal ansi by default ?

NOTE: I did try to add `CLICOLOR=1` in `.bash_profile` file. It doesn't work.

Comment: im having the same issue here.

Comment: Have a look a the `hasColorSupport()` method in `Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput`.

Answer (score 4):

Same with you, after check the `Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput`. I install the php posix extension via `sudo yum --enablerepo=remi install php-posix` then the ansi color is enabled default!

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  On Arch Linux I found the line `extension=posix.so` in `/etc/php/php.ini` needed to be uncommented to achieve the same thing.

Comment: `dnf --enablerepo=remi install php-process` for Fedora 23

Comment: This solved my problem. I wanted to use ansi color as default in C Shell for FreeBSD. Using your answer I was able to do this installing posix via `pkg install php71-posix`